# Design for C program

Tags: c

Is it good/correct way to do like this for a robust C program

```
//File1 => Module1.h

static int Fun(int);

struct{
int (*pFn)(int)
}Interface;
```

//File2 => Module1.c

```
static int Fun(int){
//do something
}

Interface* Init(void)
{
  Interface *pInterface = malloc(sizeof(Interface));
  pInterface->pFn = Fun;
  return pInterface;
}

//File 3 => Module2.c
#include"Module1.h"
main()
{
  Interface *pInterface1 = Init();
  pInterface1->pFn(5);
}
```

My intention is to make each module expose an interface...

Questions:

1. Is it good to write a C code like above to expose an interface... ??
2. What better ways are available for exposing interface??
3. Are there any references for design principles for C programming (not C++) ??

Comment: Better to post one [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: You forgot the `typedef` for the `Interface` type.

Comment: Yes, Assuming typedef there...is it a good design?

Comment: Looks like you'll be better off with C++. Your approach is valid so even though not very C-ish.

Comment: It's a common pattern, both for "modules" and for OOP in C. It doesn't matter much for the program being "robust" or not though.

Comment: Can you suggest any links or references for some common patterns in C structured programming

Comment: You are holding it wrong. You need to expose `Init` in your .h file, and not `Fun`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more idiomatic for a dynamically loaded module. (Or something along these lines.)

Usually an interface between two source files is defined using `extern` functions and objects which are accessed directly. You would need to make a case for doing anything more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use it for solving simple task, it may only increases code
   base and complexity. But certain places it could be useful.
   For example: If you want to implement [STRATEGY-pattern](http://www.adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%203,%20STRATEGY.pdf) in C, that is
   one way to do it.
2. You may hide content of the `Interface` struct from users by using [FIRST-CLASS ADT pattern](http://www.adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%201.pdf). Or you can combine above patterns.

Answer (score 0):

My short answer is no.

Ignoring the comments that point out that the static function should not be declared in the .h file (that is the part you want to hide -- it is static after all), here are some things to keep in mind.

It seems like you are trying to use the interface in order to de-couple the implementation from consumers of the module; a noble goal. This can allow increased flexibility as the implementation can change in the .c file without breaking calling code. However, think about the interface you have defined.

Any code using this module should be guaranteed to be able to get an Interface instance, via Init (although this needs to be included in your .h file). That Interface instance will point to the functions to use. One such function has the signature

```
int Fun(int);
```

So what have you hidden? Of course, you can change the function they are calling, but you still have to provide a function with that signature.

Alternatively, you could just define the .h as:

```
int Fun(int);
```

And then in the .c file, something like:

```
static int StaticFun(int i)
{
    // something
}

int Fun(int i)
{
    StaticFun(i);
}
```

You could make Fun call a different function based on some internal state it manages, or a config file, whatever you want. Why is this better? Besides being simpler, it is a static call; the compiler can inline the call to StaticFun, or even the function StaticFun completely, for example. Calls through function pointers usually incur a noticeable performance hit.

Now, there may be a case for an "Interface" object, such as you have defined. But I would be inclined to suggest that there isn't one in your case, not without modification.

Suppose your `Init` function changed to:

```
Interface* Init(some state info);
```

Now the Interface object you pass back can change depending on the state or configuration passed in, which allows your module to dynamically map functions. Basically, my opinion is that if you are actually calling a static function underneath, then you are working much harder than needed, and preventing compiler optimizations.

As a note, if you are going to go the Interface route (I'm working on a project with something similar right now) then may I suggest a modification? Something like...

.h file:

```
const Interface* Init(some state);
```

.c file:

```
static int FunTyp1(int);
static int FunTyp2(int);


static const Interface typ1 = { &FunTyp1 };
static const Interface typ2 = { &FunTyp2 };

const Interface* Init(some state)
{
    if (some state == type1)
       return &typ1;
    else if (some state == type2)
       return &typ2;
}
```

Advantages:

1. You probably don't want consuming code to modify the interface? At least, I can't think of a good reason.
2. Defining it statically avoids the unnecessary heap allocation and the memory leaks when consumers repeatedly request Interface objects and forget to free them (or don't know they should -- who owns this object?).
3. You can share a single (static) instance of the Interface object for all the consuming code in the process without worrying that someone changes it.

Note that by having several statically initialized instances, you can define a different "Interface" object for each function mapping you want to support.